# How to calculate fourier coefficients of sum of two discrete time with different fundamental periods

Tags: fourier-series

Assume that we have two discrete-time signals named x[n] with fundamental period 3 and fourier coefficients ak (k from 1 to 3), and y[n] with fundamental period 5 and fourier coefficients bk (k from 1 to 5). Now we want to calculate fourier coefficients for z[n] which is defined as below:
z[n]=x[n]+y[n]
How should we do this knowing nothing else about z[n]?

Comment: Is this a homework question?